# Scopes and Closures - Return anonymous function inside another anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to practice closures and scopes, with anonymous functions.

There are 4 HTML buttons, and on click, I want javascript to identify what button number they are, and how many times they've been clicked.

I am not sure if this is even properly setup.

Looking forward to your inputs and advice. Below are the code. Thanks in advance!!

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    return (function(input){
      var increment = 0;
      return function(){
      increment++;
        alert("button " + input.textContent + ":" + " has been clicked " + increment + " times." );
      }
    })(button);
  });
});
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course anonymous functions can return other functions. Functions are first-class-citizens in js. Every embedded function has access on the context of the enveloping function, except for the `this` property. You can use the context of the four forEach functions to store the number of increments. When you return something from withing an event listener, i dont know if this return is ever used somewhere. It maybe just exists the function.

```js
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    
    buttons.forEach(function(button){
      var increment = 0;
      button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        increment++;
          alert("button " + event.currentTarget.innerHTML + ":" + " has been clicked " + increment + " times." );
         }
       );
    });
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Could you clarify why store the increment outside the event listener? I guess, in general we don't want the variable and the incrementation to be in the same.. err scope? I'm still trying to grasp the basics as you can see :)

Comment: Variables that are stored in a scope only life in that scope. If you would declarate the increment in the event listener func, it would be deleted when the function is exited. Even if you write 'var increment = increment || 0;' In my example the increment lifes in the scope of the forEach function and THAT Scope is the parent scope of the event listener. Functions do not forget their parent scope.